# Dart sass ignores imports in Foundation sass files

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm adding sass and Foundation Sites sass to a project. I created a few sample scss files to test `@use` statements and make sure autoprefixing is working as expected. However, I cannot figure out why the sass command is ignoring the `@import` statements in the `foundation.scss` file. I specified the `load-path` and it's clearly finding the file, it just doesn't respect the `@imports` within.

I tried specifying an additional `--load-path=./node_modules/foundation-sites/**` just in case sass didn't know where to look for the foundation imports, but no luck.

Note: I'm specifically not using `node-sass` here as it doesn't (yet) recognize the `@use` statements, but from what I can tell this setup *should* work?

Thanks for any insight!

**Update:** On a hunch I tried swapping out the `@use` for `@import` statements in `app.scss` - same results.

**Update 2:** added a small repo to test the problem: https://github.com/webshooter/my-sass-issue

**My sass command (run via npm):**

```
sass --load-path=./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss --style=expanded ./src/scss:./public/css
```

(sass version 1.23.7 compiled with dart2js 2.6.1)

**app.scss:**

```css
@use "other";
@use "sample";
@use "foundation";

.app {
  color: #141414;
}

.prefix-example {
  display: grid;
  transition: all .5s;
  user-select: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}
```

**_other.scss:**

```css
.other {
  color: #ff9900;
};
```

**_sample.scss:**

```css
$font-stack: Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

.sample {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

**app.css:** (output)

```css
.other {
  color: #ff9900;
}

.sample {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.6.1
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */
.app {
  color: #141414;
}

.prefix-example {
  display: grid;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  user-select: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i think the correct `--load-path` to use is : `./node_modules/foundation-sites/assets`

Try to:

- [ Optional ] Replace `@use` with `@import` statements in your `app.scss` :

  ```
    @import "other";
    @import "sample";
    @import "foundation";
  ```
- Use this to compile you sass files `sass --load-path=./node_modules/foundation-sites/assets --style=expanded ./src/scss:./public/css`

this should fix the import issue

Comment: Changing `.../scss` to `.../assets` does seem to work! `@import` is going away in favor of `@use`, that's why I'm using dart-sass instead of node-sass, which doesn't support `@use` yet, but it looks like the `--load-path` change fixes everything. Thanks! :-)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear that this helped out to fix the imports issue, i cloned the github repo , the question was well formed ,upvoted it